# Behavior of assigning uint16_t to an index of std::vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v(4);
uint16_t cafe = 0xCAFE;
uint16_t babe = 0xBABE;
v[0] = cafe;
v[2] = babe;
```

The behavior I was going for would result in:

```
v[0] == 0xCA
v[1] == 0xFE
v[2] == 0xBA
v[3] == 0xBE
```

but instead I get:

```
v[0] == 0xFE
v[1] == 0x00
v[2] == 0xBE
v[3] == 0x00
```

What should I do to get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: Why do you expect assignments to `v[0]` and `v[2]` to affect `v[1]` and `v[3]`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Well I think it's easy to see why they would expect it. They expect that assigning a value too large for an integral object will overflow into the next object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code didn't work is that c++ converts the values to `uint8_t`, the type that your vector holds:

```
v[0] = (uint8_t)cafe; // conceptually
```

or

```
v[0] = (uint8_t)(cafe & 0xff); // conceptually
```

The following will do what you want:

```
v[0] = (uint8_t)((cafe >> 8) & 0xff);
v[1] = (uint8_t)((cafe >> 0) & 0xff);
v[2] = (uint8_t)((babe >> 8) & 0xff);
v[3] = (uint8_t)((babe >> 0) & 0xff);
```

If you have a big-endian machine, do not mind your code being unportable, and want to do some extreme performance optimization, do this:

```
*(uint16_t)&v[0] = cafe;
*(uint16_t)&v[2] = babe;
```

Comment: If your compiler is clever and doesn't mind breaking broken code, it may remove your "extremely optimized code" entirely (though arguably that *would* increase performance).

Comment: I'd label this behavior as "unportable code" (i.e. works with current moderately clever compiler; won't work with future, really clever version). Also, I believe `memcpy` has better chance to work with such aggressive optimizations by compiler (not sure though); cannot recomment it because I had no experience with it.

Comment: His optimized code is fine (except it should be `*(uint16_t*)&v[0] = cafe;`.

`&v[0]` is a char pointer which can alias anything, so no strict alias breaking here. It's also well defined on x86/x64, though it would give you `FECABEBA` because it's little endian.

You should however use `reinterpret_cast()` to highlight that you're doing a hack, and go though a `void*` to tell the compiler that you alias another type: `*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&v[0])) = cafe;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want those four elements to have those four values, set those four elements to those values. There's no mystery here, other than why you would expect some other way to work.